# Type error in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I have the following node definition:

```
{
    "prestashop_sites" : {
       "site1": { "username": "dave", "password" :"password123", "URL":"www.madeup.com" },
       "site2": { "username": "dave2", "password" :"password12", "URL":"www.madeup2.com" }
    },
       "run_list": [
       "recipe[prestashop]"
    ]
}
```

And the recipe:

```
node["prestashop_sites"].each do |site|
        username site['username']
        Chef::Log.debug("Found a server: #{site['username']}")
end

remote_file "/tmp/prestashop152.zip" do
        source "http://www.prestashop.com/download/old/prestashop_1.5.2.0.zip"
        mode "0644"
        checksum "37aee9ef5388376e4377aeb240ab027e"
        backup false
        not_if "test -f /tmp/prestashop152.zip"
end

execute "unzip -o /tmp/prestashop152.zip -d #{node[:prestashop][:location]}" do
        not_if "test -f /var/www/#{node[:prestashop][:user]}/prestashop/index.php"
end
```

So my goal is to install several instances of prestashop (after I complete the script).

But i'm stuck:

```
10:  node["prestashop_sites"].each do |site| 
11>>    Chef::Log.debug("Found a server: #{site['username']}")
12:  end

Mon, 12 Nov 2012 21:26:14 +0100] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: 
                                        TypeError - can't convert String into Integer
```

Any idea why ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a hash as a subelement of *node["prestashop_sites"]*, not an array. So you have to provide 2 variables to *each* method. 1 is for key, another for value:

```
10>>!  node["prestashop_sites"].each do |key, site| 
11:    Chef::Log.debug("Found a server: name: #{key}, #{site['username']}")
12:  end
```

Will print *"Found a server: name: site1, dave"* for the first site.

The "strange" error you get: *TypeError - can't convert String into Integer*, is because when you provide only 1 variable to the each method, ruby tries to put both key and value into that variable. Which ends the value of [key, value] assigned, which in your case means that

*site* == ["site", { "username": "dave", "password" :"password123", "URL":"www.madeup.com" }]

An array actually, and you try to access an array element with string index and not integer.